# jquery setting css dynamically slows down page

Tags: jquery, performance, loading, cell

I have a page with a very large data table. the page loads fast but then I want to apply a certain style to the cells that are empty to draw attention to them. so before I show the table I use

```
$("table td:empty").addClass("emptyCell");
```

but this is making the page take a while to load (and also stalls the loading gif I use but that's another issue all together). Does anyone have a better idea to style the empty table cells? is there a css selector I'm not aware of? the client only needs the site to work in firefox but a cross browser solution is better.

Thanks

Comment: can you do this programmaticly and add the class when you are creating the table?

Comment: oh yeah.. once again the obvious solution is hiding in plain sight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about IE (versions 8 or less) you could use this [CSS3 pseudo-class](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty).

```
table td:empty {
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that known as a *pseudo class*?

Comment: Ahem... why yes, yes it is. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up leaving it the way I had it. Further testing proved the problem to be more complex but I was able to improve overall performance slightly